# Why are we removing on-hold questions that've been improved?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829073/update-button-text-on-click/) yesterday that had been put on-hold for no MCVE.

The OP (*a new member*) needed a little instruction and with some editing help the question had sufficient information to provide a definitive answer as to why his code wasn't working.

Note: *this is the only version I could pull from Google Cache*

> I'm trying to change the text inside of a button in the click event
>   after an ajax request has completed successfully.
>
> For some reason I am unable to update the text.
>
> Jquery:
>
> ```
>   $(".addfriend").click(function(){
>      $.ajax({
>         type: "POST",
>         url: "/pages/send_friend_request.php",
>         data: {userid: $(this).data('userid')},
>         success: function(data) {
>            if(data == 'success')
>               $(this).html(' Request Sent');
>            else
>               alert('Error: Could not send request. > Report this to admin.');
>         }
>      });
>   });
> ```
>
> HTML Button:
>
> ```
> <button class="addfriend" data-userid="<?=$member['id']?>" type="button" name="button">+Add as Friend</button>
> ```

The reason why the text isn't being updated is because the use of `$(this)` within the ajax callback without providing context or a reference.

No, the question is not a gem and could've used some more editing, but, it is an answerable question that *was* on-topic, so, why was it deleted?

Comment: It seems the question was deleted because the OP was deleted. In the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36829073/timeline), there is "User 6248787 deleted" and the question was deleted by Community.

Comment: Yeah, but, shouldn't the question just be disassociated with the OP's account? The question had an accepted answer. To be clear, I'm not real worried about the rep, just hate seeing on-topic, answered questions deleted.

Comment: No, it was negatively scored. See point 10 here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222 *The system will automatically delete any question (and its answers) or answer with a negative score when its owner’s account is deleted.*

Comment: Ouch, that's rough. Thanks for the info @Tunaki. Would you mind posting that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was deleted because:

- The OP's account was deleted;
- The question was negatively scored.

From the [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222) FAQ (point 10):

> The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199860/255554) any question (and its answers) or answer with a negative score when its owner’s account is deleted.

This can also be seen in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36829073/timeline) of the post:

[image]

The fact that the question had an accepted answer apparently isn't taken into account.

Comment: FYI, I cannot see the timeline. I am a mere mortal <10k.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ Hence the screenshot. I never lose an occasion to have a nice red circle :).

Comment: Specifically, I deleted the account because it was the third account of a question-ban-evading user who had taken to insulting members of the site. They are no longer welcome to participate on this site, and will find it much more difficult to create a new account from their current location.